# New badge idea: Bravery

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Awarded for those who **engage in exceptional acts of bravery while in the line of duty.**

**Here's what happens**: it's not rare some of us go [way beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770579/176769) the standard procedure to help someone out, and the possibility to go into *chat* is awesome. It prevents a long list of comments in the main page of the thread and adds more flexibility to the communication (allowing to copy/paste code and stuff more easily).

The thing is that sometimes new users come very desperate to Stackoveflow looking for help, and with the lack of proper English, they end up getting impacient and frustrated very fast, and that can lead to [loosing control over themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792850/176769) making things get ugly, with offensive posts being fired for no reason (the offensive posts in this reference were already flagged and removed).

That's where the Bravery badge comes in. The idea is to award users who went beyond their duty trying to help others and got stabbed while doing it.

Technically speaking, we could **award the Bravery badge when a user moved the discussion to a chat, and then flagged at least one of the OP's message as offensive**.

I'm accepting suggestions as for the *class* of the badge (silver/bronze).

Comment: *when a user moved the discussion to a chat* how you'll catch that automatically?

Comment: @om-nom-nom It's a feature provided by the system if a comment thread goes on too long

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Oh, didn't know about that.

Comment: If you want to reward users who go the extra mile, does it really matter whether they get, uh, "stabbed"? (I don't think the military analogy is really working for you here.)

Comment: Don't think it's a good idea in this current format. Maybe just a "simple" bronze badge awarded for the first time you moved a discussion to chat, no strings attached.

Comment: Wait, so you're supposed to find someone who doesn't speak English well and gets pissed off very easily... and try to help them?

Comment: So I'm rewarded for moving a comment thread into chat and then flagging one of that users' posts in chat? Seems like a great way to be a jerk.

Comment: @BenBrocka that's a good name for a badge. [Jerk].

Comment: @animuson That was just an example, I saw it happens today.

Comment: The purpose of the badge system is to simply reward users for certain behaviors. I still think it is a good idea to reward someone who invested a lot of time and effort into helping someone else 1-on-1 and got shot during that process. Personally, after what happened today (twice with the same user) I'm considering to give up helping others in the comment section. The truth is that I'm here for the points, and helping others this way seems like a great waste of time and energy. I don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: 17 DOWNVOTES !! @karlphillip: Sad thing man.. :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a really original idea, but

- the number of cases that this would cover is likely to be very small
- not every occurrence of an offensive flag is indeed a user running amok - it could be somebody just using the f-word for emphasis, and some other user not liking it.
- the rule you describe would not catch all occurrences of bravery - what about the tons of abuse that happens in normal comments?
- It would be terribly easy to game
- Extended one-on-one support is a nice gesture, but doesn't need encouragement
- More cynical people might call giving extended one-on-one support that ends in the user hurling expletives "dumb" rather than "brave". ;) (dont get me wrong - I do it often enough. But I've often regretted it as well.)

so I don't think this would work.

Comment: *"Extended one-on-one support is a nice gesture, but doesn't need encouragement."* **This.** And really only this.

Comment: The purpose of the question was to **start a discussion**, aiming to reward users that go way beyond what is usually expected, and get hurt during that process. I never thought we should blindly follow the form I proposed. I'm actually hoping someone will suggest a better (technical) way to evaluate this scenario. I understand what you are saying, it's valid. Thanks.

Comment: @Cody I totally agree with that. I must have been really high (on caffeine) when I proposed this badge :)